# Loading images in React with Webpack

Tags: image, reactjs, webpack, png

I'm having trouble getting a simple image to show up in a simple app using Webpack and React.

I've read this thru and tried a few different ways, but keep getting various errors, or at best sometimes no errors, but also no image displaying.

Here is my React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../css/main.css';

import Menu from './Menu';

const logo = require('./images/PIVX_Planet_1a_239x83.png');

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {test: 'foo'};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id='container'></div>

        <div className={styles.logo}>
          <img src={logo}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Menu/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my webpack config:

```
...
module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0", "react-hmre"]
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        limit: 25000,
      },
    }, {
      test: /\.json?$/,
      loader: 'json'
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style!css?modules&localIdentName=[name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]'
    }]
  }
...
```

With this, get error from webpack in console:

> ERROR in ./app/components/App.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./images/PIVX_Planet_1a_239x83.png in /Users/mac/_DEV/_LAB/PIVX/PIVX-Planet-2/app/components
>   @ ./app/components/App.js 67:11-56

I've also tried using babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-img-import
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-img-import)

And then just use:

```
<div className={styles.logo}>
  <img src="./images/PIVX_Planet_1a_239x83.png"/>
</div>
```

In that case, there are no errors, but the image show up broken.

I've tried changing the relative path to the image with all these combinations.

Directory structure:

- app

  - components

    - App.js
  - images

    - PIVX_Planet_1a_239x83.png
  - index.html
    ...

Any insights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your directory structure the path that you need to use is

```
const logo = require('../images/PIVX_Planet_1a_239x83.png');
```

since images is under `app` directory and not under `components` from where you are trying to get the `image` location

Also make sure all your `loaders` are properly installed

Comment: that worked!  thank you.  not sure how that got missed (i had tried it).  i also had to install: npm install url-loader

Comment: i tried.  system says i need 15+ reputation to do so (and i only have 10 right now).

Comment: (i could not vote up yet, but did accept as answer) . thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can also try let as:

```
let logo = require('../images/PIVX_Planet_1a_239x83.png');
```

Always use let as much as possible to avoid the scope monster

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was using

```
import logo from './images/PIVX_Planet_1a_239x83.png'
```

instead of

```
const logo = require('./images/PIVX_Planet_1a_239x83.png');
```

in a typescript react app w/ a bespoke webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried everything that you guys have suggested but nothing is working for me. when I put my code in and 'run dev' it come out with an error placeholder. I am using it in the app.js and would like my logo as a link to the home page or just show up at all, in this case I was  attempting to just have it on the page.

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import Link from 'next/link'
import bpdlogofull from '../public/bpdlogofull.png'


    `function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
      return (
        <div>
          <nav className="border-b p-6">
            <img src={bpdlogofull} alt='logo'className='flex justify-end'/>
            <div className="flex mt-4">
              <Link href="/" className="home-button">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).